# Formik FieldArray error messages - React Native

Tags: react-native, formik

I'm using Formik `FieldArray` as part of my form and would like to show error messages, I can access the error messages within a component via `errors.familyMembers[0]`, which looks like

```
[{"first_name": "First Name is a required field", "last_name": "Last Name is a required field"}]
```

To show the error I have 2 parts where I need to extract the error message

```
isInvalid={fieldName in errors.familyMembers[0] && touched[fieldName]}

<FormErrorMessage
  message={errors.familyMembers[0][fieldName]}
  isVisible={touched[fieldName]}
/>
```

The problem is when the component is initially rendered `errors.familyMembers[0]` is `undefined`, which gives me the error

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'errors.familyMembers[0]')
```

Is there a way I can guard against `undefined` and have the messages show if available? Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Optional chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), like:

```
isInvalid={errors?.familyMembers && fieldName in errors.familyMembers[0] && touched[fieldName]}

<FormErrorMessage
  message={errors?.familyMembers?.[0][fieldName]}
  isVisible={touched[fieldName]}
/>
```

> The optional chaining operator (`?.`) enables you to read the value of a
> property located deep within a chain of connected objects without
> having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

Comment: Thank you so much, never used the ? Optional chaining operator, I’ll be making more use of this that’s for sure… thank you again 